# Is there a collective-noun for what is created by running docker-compose

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, terminology, swarm

I used docker-compose a lot, but I have never come across the collective-noun of what results from running docker-compose. I feel like calling the infra that docker-compose creates and "cluster" or a "swarm" is not entirely accurate. The technology is similar to kubernetes and docker swarm, but not exactly the same. Inferring from the name it could be a "composition", but I am not sure if that is as distinct or identifiable compared to "cluster" or "swarm".

Has anyone coined a distinct name / collective-noun for what docker-compose creates?

Comment: Questions asking for names of things belongs on [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/), not on Stack Overflow (yes, [even questions about programming](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=programming)).